# Derived Category of the Fano 4fold variety of lines

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, projective-geometry, fano-varieties

Let $X\subset P^5$ be a smooth cubic fourfold. It is well known that its variety of lines $F(X)$ is a smooth fourfold Fano variety. Hence its derived category should have a semi-orthogonal decomposition. Is a SOD of $D^b(F(X))$ known?

Comment: What do you mean by "Fano variety"?  The classical name for a Hilbert scheme parameterizing linear subschemes of a given projective variety is a "Fano scheme".  However, the dualizing sheaf of $F(X)$ is trivial.  Thus $F(X)$ is not "Fano" in the sense of having anti-ample dualizing sheaf.

Comment: Of course you are right! I was mistaken by a comment on another question, my apologies.

Comment: $F(X)$ is a famous example of hyper-K\"ahler manifold deformation equivalent to $\mathrm{Hilb}^2(K3)$ (see Beauville-Donagi). The derived category of a (connected) variety with trivial canonical bundle has no non-trivial SOD. This is a standard trick due to Bridgeland.

Comment: Of course you are both right. It's embarrassing how I messed it out in my mind! Thanks anyway for caring to show me I was nonsense.